# Django: Set an alias to the group by (annotate) field of Model.objects.filter

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

When group by is used on a Django Model filtering, how can we set an alias/label to the order by field in the response?

```
now = datetime.now()

Attendance.objects.filter(member_id=user_id, date__gte=now.date()).values('attdate__week_day').annotate(
attendance_amount=Count('attdate__week_day'))
```

This returns the following.

```
{
"attdate__week_day": 2,
"attendance_amount": 2
}
```

In above result set I need to change the "date__week_day" to "day". Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`F expression`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions) in `values()` directly:

```
Attendance.objects.filter(member_id=user_id, date__gte=now.date()).values(day=F('attdate__week_day')).annotate(
attendance_amount=Count('day'))
```

Or [`ExtractWeekDay`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/database-functions/#django.db.models.functions.ExtractWeekDay) function if you need extract only weekday:

```
Attendance.objects.filter(member_id=user_id, date__gte=now.date()).values(day=ExtractWeekDay('attdate')).annotate(
attendance_amount=Count('day'))
```

Comment: It gives the date (2020-01-15) instead of the weekday for "day".

Comment: @TechyTee ah, didn't understand your problem. Check updated answer.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, use this:

```
Attendance.objects.filter(
    member_id=user_id, date__gte=now.date()
).annotate(
    day=F('date__week_day')
).values('day').annotate(
    attendance_amount=Count('day')
)
```

Comment: This gives date instead of the weekday for the alias "day". Ex: {"day":"2020-02-01", "attendance_amount": 2 }